# How to make Django 2.1 to accept PATCH/DELETE requests

Tags: django, rest

I am building an app with Django 2.1 and I want to be able to do PATCH/DELETE requests through ajax calls. Through researching about this I found out the solution to be to deceive the browser by using a POST request, but setting the header X_METHODOVERRIDE to the desired method.

I would start doing this by creating a middleware that will take care of this. What is the best way of doing?

Please note that I don't want to use Django-REST

Code so far for making the DELETE request:

view.py

```
class CategoryManageView(StaffRequiredMixin, View):
    model = Category
    response_dict = {'status': False, 'text': '', 'data': {}}

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        cat = get_object_or_404(Category, request.POST['id'])
        self.response_dict['data'] = cat
        cat.delete()
        self.response_dict['status'] = True
        self.response_dict['text'] = 'Category deleted successfuly'
        return JsonResponse(self.response_dict)
```

If the ajax call method is set to DELETE instead of POST or GET I get error in console:

> DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/admin/categories/manage 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: This question is very confusing. You can do PUT and DELETE calls directly from your Ajax calls already, no need to "deceive" anything. And why would middleware have anything to do with this?

Comment: You can extend django View.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Why is the question confusing? If i set the method of ajax call to be PUT or DELETE i get a request forbidden error. Please offer an example if you know something is working.

Comment: Then you should show that error. Probably you haven't allowed your view to accept those methods - if you're using a class-based view for example, you need to define `put` and `delete` methods.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Let's take just the example of the delete method. I updated the question to contain the code in views.py so you can see that I have defined the delete method. Is there a way that you know of to make this work? I would highly apreciate a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code 403 indicates that this is because of CSRF protection. As [the CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/) shows, PUT and DELETE - as well as POST - are considered "unsafe" methods, and Django therefore disallows the requests if they don't have a valid CSRF token.

The same page has documentation on how to enable the token in your Ajax requests. Alternatively - although this is strongly discouraged - you can use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on the view to disable the protection.

Comment: Thank you for answering, indeed, it's related to the csrf. The request object in Django does not have a DELETE querydict like POST to insert the csrf token into. That's the problem..

Comment: From what I see I can do a middleware to check for method and create the querydict on the request object like this request.DELETE = QueryDict(request.body). I should set the CSRF in the header, not in the body of the request, i understand

Comment: You don't need to insert the token into a querydict, you put it in the header as shown in that documentation. You absolutely do not need a middleware in Django, this is all on the Ajax side.

Comment: I was supplying the csrf token with {% csrf_token %} then copying it into the ajax's data object and it worked alright with POST requests, i need to change this now